Hosting Orleans within Azure App Service using a Linux container
I have the following setup with Orleans to allow for clustering. Using Docker locally, I can spin up two instances with the code below, and both instances join the cluster successfully.
builder.Host.UseOrleans((context, siloBuilder) =>
{
    siloBuilder.Services.AddSerializer(serializerBuilder => { serializerBuilder.ConfigureSerializer(); });  
     
    siloBuilder
        .ConfigureEndpoints(11111, 30000, listenOnAnyHostAddress: true)
        .UseAzureStorageClustering(opt =>
        {
            opt.TableName = "linuxOrleansSiloInstances";
            opt.TableServiceClient =
                new TableServiceClient(settings.TableStorageConfig.ConnectionString);
        })
        .Configure<ClusterOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.ClusterId = settings.ClusterConfiguration.ClusterId;
            options.ServiceId = settings.ClusterConfiguration.ServiceId;
        });
});

I want to host it in an Azure App Service within a Linux container. The first instance spins up correctly, but I start seeing the errors below when the second instance attempts to join the cluster.
Exception while sending message: Orleans.Runtime.Messaging.ConnectionFailedException: Unable to connect to endpoint S169.254.129.15:11111:94653375. See InnerException
 ---> Orleans.Networking.Shared.SocketConnectionException: Unable to connect to 169.254.129.15:11111. Error: ConnectionRefused
   at Orleans.Networking.Shared.SocketConnectionFactory.ConnectAsync(EndPoint endpoint, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/Orleans.Core/Networking/Shared/SocketConnectionFactory.cs:line 65

Here is my partial Dockerfile setup attempting to expose ports 11111 and 30000:
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:9.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app

EXPOSE 5000
EXPOSE 11111
EXPOSE 30000

# Build stage uses the .NET SDK for build
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:9.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src

...

The only documentation I could find was here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/orleans/deployment/deploy-to-azure-app-service#configure-host-networking, which mentions the following:
If deploying to Linux, ensure that your hosts are listening on all IP addresses as described in the Configure host networking section.
According to my understanding, I have already configured this in the code example above.
Any ideas on how this can be fixed?

using NET Aspire ?

No, I am only using Orleans.

App Service currently allows your container to expose only one port for HTTP requests. You need virtual network integration as outlined here:

Orleans applications are designed to scale up and scale out efficiently. To accomplish this, instances of your application communicate directly with each other via TCP sockets and therefore Orleans requires network connectivity between silos. Azure App Service supports this requirement via virtual network integration and additional configuration instructing App Service to allocate private network ports for your app instances.


I previously had success hosting with an app service that was Windows-based, using a code deployment where I had to use the private IP and ports extracted as environment variables. However, it seems that when you switch to Linux, it uses Docker as the underlying technology, and those environment variables are no longer available.
